# Better way of copying InputStream to OutputStream

Tags: java, performance, io, nio, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is there a better way of copying `InputStream` to `OutputStream`?

I have an input stream provided by, say, `HttpClient`. I have another stream which is connected to servlet output stream.

To copy data from input stream to output stream I am using apache `IOUtils.copy` method which uses a temporary buffer for copying.

I am wondering if I use `ByteBuffer` will it help performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get away without a buffer with streams, unless you want to copy a byte at a time, which isn't efficient unless you know there are buffered streams in the stack for both input and output.

You can't use `ByteBuffers` with streams. You can use them with channels, and you can get channels from streams, but all you're doing is adding extra layers over the streams API. You're better off confronting it direct, as below. In the case of network streams, the performance is dominated by the network, not by the code, in any case.

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Works for all sizes of `buffer` greater than zero. I usually use 8192.